# Ride, SSH password begins with Hash sign and i want to assign it to a variable. Any chance?

Tags: robotframework-ide

In the tests with Ride that i have to run (not written by me), there is a variable which holds the password to a server (i can Putty to it). this password changes once per 3 months. This time unfortunately the password begins with hash sign. so when i try ti add the value to this variable using Ride, it modifies it and place it as a COMMENT for that variable and it doesn't consider it as its VALUE.
Is there anyway that i can do to assign to this pass a value begining with #?
Variable:${Pass_SSH_intA}
Password value:#34(]

Thank you

Comment: You should have pasted here the code (without real values), because it may depend on how you are defining the variable. Another thing is, if the test runs with Robot, or if not (then is a problem on Robot, not RIDE). There was recently some improvements on the # comments, but I don't recommend using the current development version, because there are some more new bugs.

Comment: I added an backslash in the beginning of this password, and it worked. but i wonder if my password string is like:   #A$@\mp   should i add anti slash for all the following characters?  # $ @ \      meaning   \#A\$\@\\mp